# How to write function to extract specific data?

Tags: function, extract, square-bracket, economics

I want to write a function to plot desired model fridgerators' daily price.
Here is a mini example with my problem:

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE,text='
date price model
    2012-01-01 100 Frenchdoor
    2012-01-01 150 Bottom
    2012-01-02 110 Frenchdoor
    2012-01-02 160 Bottom
    ')
```

And this is my mini function:

```
model <- function(model){
    data <- data[data$model=='model',]
    return(data)
}
```

But when I try to use the function,

```
model(Frenchdoor)
```

it returns no data: `<0 rows>` (or `0-length row.names`)

Without function, it works fine:

```
data <- data[data$model=='Frenchdoor',]
data
```

How do I correct my function?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in the function above.

First, by putting *model* in single quotes within your function, you are passing the function the string 'model', not the argument value provided in the statement model(Frenchdoor).

Second, if you are explicitly referencing a character string, not an R object, you should be passing your function a string. So, model('Frenchdoor') will work but model(Frenchdoor) will not.

Consider the following revision:

```
data <-read.table(header=TRUE, text='
date price model
    2012-01-01 100 Frenchdoor
    2012-01-01 150 Bottom
    2012-01-02 110 Frenchdoor
    2012-01-02 160 Bottom
')

model <- function(model){
data <- data[data$model==model,]
return(data)
}
```

Finally, it is really best practice to provide argument names that are different from the function name. Because model is a name in your dataframe, I recommend renaming the function. Taken together, something like this would be a bit cleaner:

```
FilterByModel <- function(model){
data <- data[data$model==model,]
return(data)
}
```